# FFmpeg - mapping 4 audio channels to 1 audio track

Tags: qt, audio, ffmpeg

I have two QT MOV's that I want to concatenate using FFmpeg, but I am having trouble understanding how to map the audio channels.

First MOV has 2 channels, Front Left and Front Right. Second MOV has 4 channels, Front Left, Front Right, Side Left and Side Right.

How do I create 1 audio track with 4 channels mapped as FL, FR, SL and SR?

MediaInfo reports the following (not desired result):

```
Audio #1
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 4mn 35s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 126 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 160 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel(s)_Original                      : 4 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L C R, Side: C
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 fps (1024 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 4.14 MiB (12%)
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1

Audio #2
ID                                       : 3
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 4mn 35s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 127 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 160 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel(s)_Original                      : 4 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L C R, Side: C
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 fps (1024 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 4.18 MiB (12%)
Default                                  : No
Alternate group                          : 1

Audio #3
ID                                       : 4
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 4mn 35s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 110 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 160 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel(s)_Original                      : 4 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L C R, Side: C
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 fps (1024 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 3.62 MiB (10%)
Default                                  : No
Alternate group                          : 1

Audio #4
ID                                       : 5
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 4mn 35s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 110 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 160 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel(s)_Original                      : 4 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L C R, Side: C
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 fps (1024 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 3.61 MiB (10%)
Default                                  : No
Alternate group                          : 1
```

FFmpeg command is as follows:

```
`ffmpeg -i "2chan.mov" -i "4chan.mov" -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]; [v]scale=-1:288[v2]; [a]channelsplit=channel_layout=quad(side)[FL][FR][SL][SR]" -map "[v2]" -map "[FL]" -map "[FR]" -map "[SL]" -map "[SR]" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 700k -minrate 700k -maxrate 700k -bufsize 700k -r 25 -sc_threshold 25 -keyint_min 25 -g 25 -qmin 3 -qmax 51 -threads 8 -c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 160k -ar 48000 -async 1 -ac 4 combined.mp4`
```

Console output:

```
  ffmpeg version N-77883-gd7c75a5 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
      configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
    isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
    le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
    enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
    ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
    le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
    able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --ena
    ble-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
     --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
    e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --
    enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
      libavutil      55. 13.100 / 55. 13.100
      libavcodec     57. 22.100 / 57. 22.100
      libavformat    57. 21.101 / 57. 21.101
      libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
      libavfilter     6. 25.100 /  6. 25.100
      libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
      libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
      libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000000000575c00] ignoring 'frma' atom of 'mp4a', str
eam format is 'mp4a'
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2chan.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2016-01-19 05:48:38
  Duration: 00:00:45.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 364 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte1
70m/smpte170m/bt709), 768x576, 196 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn
, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-01-19 05:48:40
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, flt
p, 159 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-01-19 05:48:42
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-01-19 05:49:42
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005da420] ignoring 'frma' atom of 'mp4a', str
eam format is 'mp4a'
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '4chan.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2016-01-19 04:11:52
  Duration: 00:19:58.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5118 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte1
70m/smpte170m/bt709), 768x576, 4955 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50k tbc (defa
ult)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-01-19 04:11:52
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
      timecode        : 00:28:33:21
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, quad, fltp,
 157 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-01-19 04:11:52
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #1:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 0
      creation_time   : 2016-01-19 04:11:52
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:28:33:21
File 'Output_Complex_6.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
-async is forwarded to lavfi similarly to -af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.
100000:first_pts=0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 Cache64
 SlowShuffle
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] profile High, level 2.1
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] 264 - core 148 r2638 7599210 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC cod
ec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r
ef=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed
_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pski
p=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=8 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 deci
mate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_
adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=25 keyint_min=13
 scenecut=25 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=25 rc=cbr mbtree=1 bitrate=700 ratetol
=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=3 qpmax=51 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=700 vbv_bufsize=700 nal_hr
d=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'Output_Complex_6.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    title           : TestTitle
    encoder         : Lavf57.21.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 384x28
8 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=3-51, 700 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.22.100 libx264
    Side data:
      unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, 4.0, fltp,
160 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.22.100 aac
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, 4.0, fltp,
160 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.22.100 aac
    Stream #0:3: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, 4.0, fltp,
160 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.22.100 aac
    Stream #0:4: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, 4.0, fltp,
160 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.22.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> concat:in0:v0
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat:in0:a0
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> concat:in1:v0
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> concat:in1:a0
  scale -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  channelsplit:FL -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
  channelsplit:FR -> Stream #0:2 (aac)
  channelsplit:SL -> Stream #0:3 (aac)
  channelsplit:SR -> Stream #0:4 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   85 fps=0.0 q=3.0 size=       6kB time=00:00:02.68 bitrate=  18.8kbits/s
frame=  150 fps=148 q=3.0 size=      14kB time=00:00:05.24 bitrate=  21.3kbits/s
frame=  198 fps=130 q=3.0 size=      65kB time=00:00:07.21 bitrate=  74.4kbits/s
frame=  238 fps=118 q=3.0 size=     125kB time=00:00:08.78 bitrate= 116.2kbits/s
frame=  271 fps=108 q=3.0 size=     171kB time=00:00:10.09 bitrate= 138.9kbits/s
frame=  304 fps=100 q=3.0 size=     218kB time=00:00:11.45 bitrate= 156.0kbits/s
frame=  339 fps= 96 q=3.0 size=     268kB time=00:00:12.84 bitrate= 171.0kbits/s
frame=  372 fps= 93 q=-1.0 Lsize=     376kB time=00:00:14.80 bitrate= 208.0kbits
/s speed=3.69x
video:27kB audio:319kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
overhead: 8.551113%
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] frame I:15    Avg QP: 3.01  size:  1370
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] frame P:90    Avg QP: 3.00  size:    24
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] frame B:267   Avg QP: 3.00  size:    17
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] consecutive B-frames:  4.3%  0.0%  0.0% 95.7%
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] mb I  I16..4: 95.8%  0.0%  4.2%
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.1%  0.0
%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.9%
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.0%  0.0
%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:100.0%  L0: 0.0% L1:100.0% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] 8x8 transform intra:0.0% inter:50.0%
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 3.1% 8.8% 8.2% inter: 0.0%
 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] i16 v,h,dc,p: 90%  5%  5%  0%
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 46% 29% 23%  0%  0%
 0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] i8c dc,h,v,p: 76%  7% 17%  0%
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 000000000057d260] kb/s:14.64
[aac @ 0000000000578320] Qavg: 65394.652
[aac @ 0000000000593020] Qavg: 65473.359
[aac @ 0000000000593940] Qavg: 65536.000
[aac @ 0000000000594260] Qavg: 65536.000
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? Y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the channelsplit since you want only 1 stream. Use channelmap instead:

`...;[a]channelmap=map=FL|FR|SL|SR[outa]"`. And map `"[outa]"`.

Comment: Hi Mulvya, thanks for your assistance. When I tried the channel map it is missing one channel with the following MediaInfo result:

Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel(s)_Original                 : 4 channels
Channel positions                    : Front: L C R, Side: C

Comment: Did some experimenting, and seems the AAC encoder doesn't respect the output of channelmap. I'll see if there's another way.

Comment: Hi Mulvya, sorry for late reply. Thank you so much for discovering the issue. I was starting think something was wrong with the original files. I will try PCM and let you know in the next day or two. Again, much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Mulvya, background on how the files are created. I use Digital Rapids Stream software/hardware. With the chosen combination of QT AVC and PCM codec, I have 41 audio mapping options, from Mono to Octagonal up to 21 audio channels. Only 4 channel mapping variations for quadraphonic.

Comment: Created new files, Quicktime, AVC, 24bit PCM @ 48KHz, Quadraphonic audio (FL, FR, SL, SR). When I omit the audio channel map from FFmpeg the audio channels are correct on the resulting MP4 but the audio sounds like it drops out or is struggling to play back at a consistent frame rate.  MediaInfo reports only 2 channels of audio (should this be 4?), with 4 original channels with a mapping of L, C, R, SC and an odd audio frame rate of 46.875 fps (1024 spf). I now only need to  rectify the audio playback issue. If I include the channel map, the mapping is incorrect and one channel is missing.

Comment: Paste the console output into your Q.

Comment: Hi Mulvya. It appears various media players handle the audio in the MP4 differently. For example Windows Media Player plays channels 1 (L), 2 (R) but not 3 and 4. Quicktime Player plays channels 1, 2 but combines channels 3 and 4. Professional media player Atlas, from Archimedia Technologies, all channels play correctly. Resolved the audio playback issue by increasing the audio bit rate to 320 from 160.

Comment: The audio fps isn't odd - they don't correspond to video framerate. Each AAC frame contains a fixed number of samples - 1024. So if sampling rate is 48000 Hz then there will be 48000 / 1024 = 46.875 frames per second. It's strange that the bitrate solves the drop out problem. They should not be related. But anyway, it works now.